# Is it possible to loop through 10^8 possibilities to determine the correct answer?

Tags: python, gmpy

I have a number which is 615 digits long. Throughout it, there are 8 places where digits are missing. I have to find out what the digits are. There are 10^8 possibilities.

It is for an RSA problem. The number in question is the private key, and I am trying to find out what it is. To help me, I have the public key pair (n, e), both of which are also 615 digits long, and also a plaintext and corresponding ciphertext.

So the only way to figure out d is to bruteforce it. I am trying to use gmpy2 in python to figure it out. I had to jump through a lot of hoops to get it to work. I do not even know if I correctly did it. I had to download Python2.7 so I could run the gmpy2 installer just to not get an error message. But I think it works now, as I can type

```
>>>import gmpy2
```

in the terminal and it doesnt give me an error.

Before I try to loop through 10^8 possibilities, I want to know if its possible to do so in a relatively short amount of time, considering my situation. I do not want to fry my computer or freeze it trying to compute this. I also want to know if I am using the right tools for this, or is gmpy2 not the correct version, or Python2.7 is not good/fast enough. I am running gmpy2 on Python2.7 on a laptop.

In the end I suppose I want to take all 10^8 answers and raise such that C^d = M mod n. So thats an (already) large number to the power of number 615 digits long, 10^8 times. Is this possible? If it is, how can I do this using gmpy2? Is there a more efficient way to compute this?

I sincerely apologize if this is not the right place to ask this. Thank you for any help.

Comment: what you've said sounds reasonable and it should complete in reasonable amounts of time.  note that integer values in python are already "arbitrary precision" (so I can do `10**615 % 7727`) and get the right answer.  I'd expand out your question to include some code that would implement your algorithm if you want people here to be able to comment more usefully

Comment: That long of a loop is never a good idea, have you tried recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the `gmpy2` maintainer.

To calculate C**d mod n, you should use the builtin `pow()` and specify all three values. `pow(C,d,n)` will be much faster than `C**d % n`.

Using `gmpy2` should be easy for this. Instead of using `int()` to covert a string to a Python integer, you just need to use `gmpy2.mpz()`. You can use `pow()` with `mpz` instances. (And if even one of the three values to `pow()` is an `mpz`, `gmpy2` will be used to for the calculation.)

I estimate running time with `gmpy2` to be range from less than an hour to a few hours. Python's native integers might be 10x slower.

Answer (score 0):

**You're not going to fry your computer.**

It may take a long time to run, but it seems like this is a straight O(n) problem, so it won't blow up to infinity. As long as it doesn't take an obscene amount of time to check if one hash is valid or not, this may even take less than a minute to run. Modern day machines measure clock cycles in gHz. That's 10^9 cycles per second. And besides, since you say you can't make any inferences on what the correct answer would be from wrong guesses, brute force seems like the only solution.